# Do metrics published by the Jaeger Operator include those from the Collector and Query services too?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, jaeger

I am deploying Jaeger using the [Jaeger Operator](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/latest/operator/) and it seems to be working fine. However, now I am trying to set up Prometheus metrics scraping (using the [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator)) but I am not seeing a `Service` in my cluster that exposes the metrics ports for the Jaeger Collector (port 14269) or Query services (port 16687) ([port number reference from the Jeager Monitoring documentation](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.21/monitoring/)).

The only relevant `Service` I see is `jaeger-operator-metrics`:

```
$ kubectl get svc -A
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)
simple-prod-collector           ClusterIP      10.43.20.131    <none>           9411/TCP,14250/TCP,14267/TCP,14268/TCP
simple-prod-query               ClusterIP      10.43.141.211   <none>           16686/TCP
simple-prod-collector-headless  ClusterIP      None            <none>           9411/TCP,14250/TCP,14267/TCP,14268/TCP
jaeger-operator-metrics         ClusterIP      10.43.90.169    <none>           8383/TCP,8686/TCP
```

I am able to set up a Prometheus `ServiceMonitor` to scrape metrics from this service but I am not sure if this includes the metrics that are normally gathered by the Collector and Query microservices or not... I am guessing not as that would seem to violate the premise of microservices.

Is there some setting in the Jaeger Operator spec that I missed for exposing those metrics endpoints in the other components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... the Jaeger Operator doesn't create a `Service` exposing the metrics endpoints. These endpoints are just exposed via the pods for the Collector and Query components.

An example from the Collector pod spec:

```
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9411
      name: zipkin
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 14267
      name: c-tchan-trft
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 14268
      name: c-binary-trft
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 14269
      name: admin-http
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 14250
      name: grpc
      protocol: TCP
```

Note the `admin-http` port there.

So to get the Prometheus Operator to scrape these metrics, I created a `PodMonitor` which covers both the Collector and Query components because both of them have the `labels/app: jaeger` and `admin-http` ports defined:

```yaml
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  name: jaeger-components
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    release: prometheus
spec:
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: admin-http
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - monitoring
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: jaeger
EOF
```